# Where can I get good raw meteorological data for Middle East?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, weather-satellites

I live in the Middle East and I am really fond of understanding meteorology and using raw data make my own weather predictions. However, a limitation I encounter here is that most raw meteorological data providers e.g. radars are only limited to the US or UK. I would like to know if there are any sources that provide professional raw weather data for the Middle East. Thank you a lot.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful

Answer (score 1):

This [work](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/gdj3.12) intend to consolidate climate data series from 79 stations in North Africa and the Middle East, between the 19th century to present day. Distribution of the stations are shown in Figure 1:

[image]

One challenge they had was an amount of incomplete records in the available dataset during that studied lapse. Table 1 and 2 show the name and location of the sources for the datasets, which could be useful for you to get started if your research need recent (2008-2018) records

Further they provided as supplemental material their raw datasets used in their research [here](https://zenodo.org/record/7531), as used in their paper (-> 2008).